# What is the difference between decision_function, predict_proba, and predict function for logistic regression problem?

Tags: regression, logistic, prediction, scikit-learn, decision-theory

I have been going through the sklearn documentation but I am not able to understand the purpose of these functions in the context of logistic regression.
For `decision_function` it says that its the distance between the hyperplane and the test instance. how is this particular information useful? and how does this relate to `predict` and `predict-proba` methods?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Recall that the functional form of logistic regression is

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \beta_k x_k)}} $$

This is what is returned by `predict_proba`.

The term inside the exponential

$$ d(x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \beta_k x_k $$

is what is returned by `decision_function`.  The "hyperplane" referred to in the documentation is

$$ \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \beta_k x_k = 0 $$

This terminology is a holdover from support vector machines, which literally estimate a separating hyperplane.  For logistic regression this hyperplane is a bit of an artificial construct, it is the plane of equal probability, where the model has determined both target classes are equally likely.

The `predict` function returns a class decision using the rule

$$ f(x) > 0.5 $$

At the risk of soapboxing, the `predict` function has very few legitimate uses, and I view using it as a sign of error when reviewing others work.  I would go far enough to call it a design error in sklearn itself (the `predict_proba` function should have been called `predict`, and `predict` should have been called `predict_class`, if anything at all).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Matthew, but can you clarify this point a bit more "For logistic regression, this hyperplane is a bit of an artificial construct, it is the plane of equal probability, where the model has determined both target classes are equally likely." ?

Comment: This explanation is interesting and helpful. I wish sklearn explained it better. What I don't understand is what is the use of knowing the value of x in the logistic function 1/(1+e^-x)? All I can think of is to possibly use a different sigmoid function like x/(1+|x|). Is there more? thanks!

Comment: Basically the decision function should have been the sigmoid in the logistic regression. Correct?

Comment: I think the reason for @Matthew being on a soapbox is that using 0.5 as the threshold for prediction is naive. The first thing one should do is learn to use cross-validation, ROC curves and AUC to choose an appropriate threshold c, and using as the decision function f(x) > c.

Comment: @Mathew Drury.   I computed ```1/(1+np.exp(-lr.decision_function(X))```, but the result does not match exactly to ```lr.predict_proba```.  They are close, but not the same.  Do you know why?

Comment: @Sarah Looks like sklearn does not use exactly that function to transform into probabilities under the hood. Instead, it uses a generalized numerically stable version of softmax: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/e217b68fd00bb7c54b81a492ee6f9db6498517fa/sklearn/utils/extmath.py#L595

Comment: @Mathew Drury.  But I checked the binary logistic regression, these two are not the same either.  For the binary logistic regression, there should not be softmax function used.

Comment: The source code does use the softmax, even in the cast of a binary logistic regression (well, as far as I can tell from reading the code).

Comment: Apparently, decision_function returns what's called "logits" in the deep learning literature.

Comment: @MatthewDrury thanks - are you aware of any examples / things to read/search for in order to support the "soapboxing" at the end of your post? Would be appreciated.